# Monogame Linux effect compilation error with wine64

Tags: c#, linux, debian, monogame, wine

When I try to compile effects (.fx files) with mgcb-editor (which works perfectly btw) :

```
dotnet mgcb /@:"/home/Monogame/ShaderTest/Content/Content.mgcb" /platform:DesktopGL /outputDir:"/home/Monogame/ShaderTest/Content/bin/DesktopGL/Content" /intermediateDir:"/home/Monogame/ShaderTest/Content/obj/DesktopGL/net6.0/Content" /workingDir:"/home/Monogame/ShaderTest/Content"
```

I have an error that the Content directory is not found...

```
An error occurred trying to start process 'wine64' with working directory '/home/Monogame/ShaderTest/Content'. No such file or directory
```

I've changed the permissions on all directories, I've reinstall everything 10 times, and nothing seem to work.

Does anybody have an idea about the issue ?

Thanks in advance